# Unity 'StartCoroutine' does not run twice when IEnumerator is passed as a variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

So I've ran into something weird, when using a **co-routine** in **Unity** to simulate a NPC (walks towards a target, idles for x seconds, walks to a target --repeat--).

I've found that starting the co-routine with a variable that holds the **IEnumerator** will not run twice, while starting the co routine with the method passed in directly runs as expected, repeatable.

Why does this work this way?
Whats happening 'under the hood'? I cant wrap my head around why this is, and it bugs me.

Below my **IEnumerator** method that simulates idle time.

```
private IEnumerator sitIdle()
{
    var timeToWait = GetIdleTime();
    _isIdle = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToWait);
    _isIdle = false;
}
```

If this gets called a second time per Scenario #1 (below), it runs as expected when called multiple times. It just repeats the process over and over.

If however, if it gets called per Scenario #2 (below) as a variable, it will kick off once, but refuse to enter a second time and just plain 'skip' it in code.

```
void LateUpdate()
    {
        _idleRoutine = sitIdle; //this is not actually in the late update, just moved here for reference.

        if (_agent.hasPath)
        {
            if (isTouchingTarget())
            {
                StartCoroutine(sitIdle2()); //Scenario #1

                StartCoroutine(_idleRoutine); //Scenario #2

                _currentTarget = null; 
                _agent.ResetPath();
            }
        }
```

Tl;dr: StartCoroutine(variable to IEnumerator) is not repeatable, while StartCoroutine(IEnumerator()) works fine, why cant I pass the IEnumerator as a variable?

Comment: The code shown in the question won't compile. Do you mean `_idleRoutine = sitIdle();`?

Comment: Is `StartCoroutine` your method, or something Unity provides? My guess would be that if it's taking an instance of `IEnumerator` that it's iterating through the `IEnumerator` by calling `MoveNext` in a `while` loop. When you pass `StartCoroutine` the result of `sitIdle` you're passing a new instance of `IEnumerator`. However, if you put the result of `sitIdle` in a variable then once you call `StartCoroutine` once, you've already iterated past the end of the `IEnumerator`. So the next time you pass it to `StartCoroutine`, `MoveNext` just returns `false`.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson Yes, see [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of `SitIdle()` is an `IEnumerator`. `IEnumerator`s do not repeat once they are completed and have no iterations remaining, which is what `StartCoroutine` tells Unity to do. Each time the coroutine is resumed at a `yield` is another iteration Unity tells the coroutine to perform.

If you really would like to store the coroutine as a variable, so you can choose between one or another, you could store the method you're interested in as a delegate, then call that to get your fresh `IEnumerator`:

```
IEnumerator sitIdle()
{
    var timeToWait = GetIdleTime();
    _isIdle = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToWait);
    _isIdle = false;
}  

IEnumerator sitIdleAlternative()
{
    var timeToWait = GetIdleTime() + 2f;
    _isIdle = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToWait);
    _isIdle = false;
}

delegate IEnumerator IdleDelegate ();

IdleDelegate _idleRoutine;

void LateUpdate()
{
    _idleRoutine = new IdleDelegate(sitIdleAlternative); //this is not actually in the late update, just moved here for reference.

    _idleRoutine = new IdleDelegate(sitIdle);

    if (_agent.hasPath)
    {
        if (isTouchingTarget())
        {
            StartCoroutine(sitIdle2()); //Scenario #1

            StartCoroutine(_idleRoutine()); //Scenario #2

            _currentTarget = null; 
            _agent.ResetPath();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that clears up my question on what unity does 'under the hood' with relation to StartCoroutine!